# How do I get translated version from templateCache?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have a form that I want to get from the template cache as string:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="info.html">
            <p> {{ 'COMMON.NAME' | translate }} </p>
</script>
```

When I call `$templateCache.get('info.html')` I get the untranslated string of the template above:

```
<p> {{ 'COMMON.NAME' | translate }} </p>
```

What I want to get is the translated version which looks like this:

```
<p> name </p>
```

Is there any way to do that with `templateCache`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

```
$scope.commonName = $templateCache.get('info.html')
```

Then in the view:

```
<p ng-bind-html="commonName | translate"></p>
```

It is important that you add [angular-sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) to your project and inject it to your app module.

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
```